# can i make jenkins pipeline not exit when curl request returns invalid status code

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline is as follows

```
pipeline{
  agent any
    stages{
       stage{
          script{
              
                 res1=sh(returnStdout:true, script: 'curl -o /dev/null -sf -w "%{http_code}" http://xyz1.jsp').replace(' ','').toInteger()
                echo "${res1}"
                
                res2=sh(returnStdout:true, script: 'curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" http://xyz2.jsp').replace(' ','').toInteger()
                echo "${res2}"
              }
        }
   }
}
```

When 1st curl request returns a status code of 000, script is returning exit code 7 and build is *failing*. But I want the 2nd curl request also to run and then fail?

Comment: In build process if one step fails then subsequent steps are not triggered by Jenkins.

Comment: Have you try put the `sh` in a `try/catch` block

Comment: i have to keep each sh in a try catch. i actually have more than 2 sh in my original script. so is there a way where we can prevent jenkins from exiting at that step